# Como fazer um menu no bash e não precisar apertar ENTER após escolher a opção?

Tags: bash, menu

Estou tentando criar um menu no bash mas não quero pressionar ENTER ao selecionar o número da opção.

O código que estou tentando usar:

```
PS3=Selecione um personagem: select character in Sheldon Leonard Penny Howard Raj

do

echo "Selected character:echo | $character" echo "Selected number:echo | $REPLY" done
```

Obrigado à todos que ajudarem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia usar `read` com o sinalizador `-n` acompanhado da quantidade de caracteres esperada. Assim, definir entrada de 1 a 9 ou de letras, permite que o caractere pressionado selecione uma opção.

Extraindo o trecho relevante de `read --help`:

```
      -n NCHARS     retorna após ler NCHARS caracteres, ao invés de esperar
                    por uma nova linha, mas respeita um delimitador se número
                    de caracteres menor que NCHARS sejam lidos antes do
                    delimitador
```

Relacionando ao seu código, poderia definir pela letra inicial:

```shell
#!/bin/bash

PS3="Selecione um personagem: select character in [S]heldon [L]eonard [P]enny [H]oward [R]aj: "

read -n 1 -p "$PS3" -s escolha
echo ""

case $escolha in
 [Ss]) personagem=Sheldon ;;
 [Ll]) personagem=Leonard ;;
 [Pp]) personagem=Penny ;;
 [Hh]) personagem=Howard ;;
 [Rr]) personagem=Raj ;;
 *) echo "Escolha inválida." ;;
esac

echo "Você escolheu $personagem"
```

Comment: Obrigado!!!!! Funcionou para mim!

Answer (score -1):

Pode usar esse script como exemplo:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "************ MENU ************"
echo "  1 - opcao 1"
echo "  2 - opcao 2"

read -n 1 -s n
case $n in
  1) echo "escolheu 1" ;;
  2) echo "escolheu 2" ;;
  *) echo "invalid option";;
esac
```